# Selenium: I can't locate element with anything

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

HTML CODE

```
<div class="dropButton" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); background-color: transparent; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 10px; border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block;"><button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; vertical-align: bottom; background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; height: 56px; width: 56px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 50%; text-align: center;"><div><div style="transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; top: 0px;"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 56px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; line-height: 56px;"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path></svg></div></div></button></div>
```

**There is no iframe**
I get this error 
`Unable to locate element`

[I tried using this command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rb7Q.png)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/header/div/button/div/div/svg').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath is not correct. Use `.dropButton button` css selector and `WebDriverWait` to wait element to be clickable. You can find helpful information about locator strategies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropButton button'))).click()
```

If there're more buttons with the selector add element with `root` id:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root .dropButton button'))).click()
```